# Canonical way to combine list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a bunch of list comprehensions that I'd like to combine.

I've got a list of objects, and I want to generate a set of lists, each of which contains some property of each of the objects in the original list. For example:

```
my_list = ["Kathryn", "John", "Eve", "Jack"]
initials = [x[0] for x in my_list]
upper_case = [x.upper() for x in my_list]
lower_case = [x.lower() for x in my_list]
```

Note that I'm looping through my original list multiple times. If I have many different properties I want to get from each element, then I'm going to be repeating this looping a lot.

Instead, I tried zipping the results of getting all properties in one single iteration:

```
initials, upper_case, lower_case = zip(*((x[0], x.upper(), x.lower()) for x in my_list))
```

This works, except (1) I think this code is rather unclear, and (2) the resulting variables are actually tuples instead of lists, so to get lists (which I need) I'd have to do something like

```
initials, upper_case, lower_case = (list(x) for x in (initials, upper_case, lower_case))
```

which, already right now, but especially if I'm extracting more than three properties, I also don't really like the looks of. ("... of which I also don't really like the looks"?)

Is there a more satisfactory, "cleaner" way to do this?

Comment: The original code with 3 list comprehensions is good, no need to try to "improve" it. Whether you loop the original data once and do 3x work per element, or loop it 3 times and do 1x work per element, it won't make any significant difference in time or memory.

Comment: @wim: Would you still think it's good if it's not 3, but, say, 20 list comprehensions? It's a very blatant violation of the DRY principle. (Though indeed I'll readily admit that the performance isn't really an issue here.)

Comment: @wim depends on the list size, how many "transformed" lists you need,  the cost of the transformations - and of course of wether the source is actually a list (it could as well be a lazy iterable fetching data from a database or an external API and then you definitly DONT want to loop thrice or more...).

Comment: The same principle, whether you loop 20x and do 1x work or loop  1x and do 20x per iteration. If you want to ask for a "more satisfactory" way to do this, you'll need to quantify what by what measure you're improving it against.

Comment: @wim as stated above, if the iteration has a higher cost than the transformation then it _does_ make a difference. Else I wholefully agree about the need to define and quantify what is effectively an "improvment"

Answer (score 2):

Plain simply, use a `for` loop instead:

```
my_list = ["Kathryn", "John", "Eve", "Jack"]
initials = []
upper_case = []
lower_case = []
for x in my_list:
    initials.append(x[0])
    upper_case.append(x.upper())
    lower_case.append(x.lower())
```

As a general rule: the first and foremost goal of list comprehensions is not to be faster but to be more readable (by reducing "line noise"). If using a list comprehension makes your code less readable, then don't use a list comprehension.

NB: this assumes you want to optimize for readability of course - sometimes you do want to optimize for speed even if it makes for less readable code, and that's ok too (as long as you compensate with clear comments / documentation so you don't want to hang yourself to the nearest tree when you have to maintain that code a few months later).

Comment: It seems just a different way to do the same thing, to me.  No better, no worse.

Comment: Well, you asked how to avoid the three list comprehensions while keeping a readable code, and that's the simplest possible answer.  wrt/ readabilty, it's indeed neither better nor worse. wrt/ perfs,  if you replace `my_list` with a lazy iterable that fetches data from some IO bound source or has a high cost producing items, then it's certainly better.

Comment: Oh and yes: it is indeed a bit slower than three list comps for your example snippet.

Comment: A lazy iterable is neither mentioned nor alluded to in the question, so it's somewhat a [straw-man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) fallacy to imagine a hypothetical situation in which loop/append provides any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are considering: clarity, tuple vs list output, extendibility to more functions.

You may wish to consider a functional solution, which could add clarity and extendibility. Such a solution may not be faster than other solutions. Here's an example:

```
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

my_list = ['Kathryn', 'John', 'Eve', 'Jack']

funcs = (itemgetter(0), methodcaller('upper'), methodcaller('lower'))

i, u, l = map(list, (map(func, my_list) for func in funcs))

print(i, u, l, sep='\n')

['K', 'J', 'E', 'J']
['KATHRYN', 'JOHN', 'EVE', 'JACK']
['kathryn', 'john', 'eve', 'jack']
```

Comment: It's worse than the original

Comment: @wim, Then downvote :). This is the risk I take when I an answer a primarily opinion-based question. In my opinion, this is cleaner and more manageable for a large number of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another DRY way of doing this is:

```
def comprehend(func, iterable):
    return [func(item) for item in iterable]

my_list = ["Kathryn", "John", "Eve", "Jack"]

Initials = comprehend(lambda x:x[0], my_list)
Upper_case = comprehend(lambda x:x.upper(), my_list)
Lower_case = comprehend(lambda x:x.lower(), my_list)
```

Comment: I don't see how "not repeating" `[ ... for x in my_list]` but instead repeating `comprehend(lambda x: ... , my_list)` is any less of a violation of DRY.

Comment: Congratulations, you just reinvented the builtin `map(func, iterable)` function !

Answer (score 0):

What you need is *map* the functions to the list to get another list with the same shape. You can specify the functions as lambdas (anonymous functions) or use methodcaller/itemgetter as the [solution of jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026120/2739274)

```
my_list = ["Kathryn", "John", "Eve", "Jack"]

initials =  list(map(lambda x:x[0] ,my_list))
upper_case = list(map(lambda x:x.upper() ,my_list))
lower_case = list(map(lambda x:x.lower() ,my_list))
```